# Can't perceive a 6-8 March rhythm properly

Tags: beats

I'm playing "the Campbells are coming" which goes like this:
[image]

As I think, it goes like (There is an anacrusis):

```
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 | 1 2 3 4 5 6 |
| - - - - - c | e g a g e c | e.. e e.. c | e g a g e c | d.. d d.. c |
```

but my backing rhythm goes like

[image]

How should i play it now?

Comment: 6/8 is march time because each bar divides into two, hence 'left, right' fits in one whole bar. I can't work out what the backing rhythm has to do with the tune.

Comment: to make the tune fit your rhythm you would have to add an extra beat to the words cambles, coming, etc. Eg. "tha ca am bles are co om ing, hu ra ah ar, hu ra ah ar"

Comment: Compound time signatures have an inherent swing rhythm to them which I'm wondering if you really want in a march. Also it would have to be compound triple time for it to have a chance of giving a march feel.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that I follow your rhythm (seems to have some extra beats, perhaps played simultaneously on different instruments?)

However, marches in 6/8 are played with two beats per measure; the individual beats are triplets. Equivalently (but not so easy to read perhaps) would be to write the piece in 2/4 with triplets. The second and fourth measure of your score show the main outline: two quarter+eighths per measure. The basic beat is a dotted quarter, not an eighth or quarter.